# Advance for loop Query rows limit?

Tags: apex, soql

```
for(Account obj : [Select Id,Name From Account])
{
    //SOme Code
}
```

If I am writing advanced for loop like above, if record limits exceeds 50K will it throw exception. I was checking around this in documentation it says it uses `Query` and `Querymore` attribute to retrive data in chunks , I got bit confuse what if SOQL query returns more than `50K records` , will it throw exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant get more than 50k rows via SOQL. Query and Querymore are present not in apex but in Rest and SOAP API. They give cursor that allows getting more records.

Internally, if you use SOQL for List's it uses to query and querrymore. But its for heap trick, not for getting more rows than what governor has specified.

```
for (List<Account> listAcc :  [Select Id,Name From Account]) {
    for(Account acc : listAcc){ //Querry and querry more is called here
     //do processing here    
 }
}
```

The only way to get more rows is use Batch or if you have UI then use PK Chunking where you keep track of last processed record Id and use ID > lastprocessedId

Comment: Thanks , I figured it out later by running SOQL in dev console having more than 50K records !